# Thunderbird does not start anymore after having restarted Windows 10

Tags: thunderbird, parallels

I have installed Thunderbird 68.4.2.7327 in a Parallels VM (Windows 10 Home 64-bit). After the installation it worked without problems. But after having restarted Windows, I cannot start Thunderbird anymore. Even if I double-click on `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe`, nothing happens! Only for a very short fraction of a second something unidentifiable appears on the on the top-left corner of the screen.

Comment: Uninstall Thunderbird, reinstall the latest version and if it still does not work start it in safe mode: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/safe-mode-thunderbird

Comment: I have found a working solution here: https://superuser.com/questions/1524279/thunderbird-does-not-reopen-mails-after-profile-migration