# Thunderbird does not reopen mails after profile migration

Tags: thunderbird

I have migrated the Thunderbird Profile folder from my Windows 7 computer to a new Windows 10 computer (which in reality is a Parallels VM with Windows 10 Home x-64 on my MacBook Pro). When I opened Thunderbird the first time after doing the Profile configuration, everything was OK, all old emails were there, I could send and receive emails and I was happy.
But when I closed Thunderbird the first time and restarted Thunderbird later, there was only an EMPTY Thunderbird window with an enlarged status bar showing this:

[image]

I repeated the whole process a few times to make sure it was not an accidental error. But it happened always in the same way: After the first closing Thunderbird on startup always presented an empty window with the above code lines!
What is going on here??

Comment: How did you migrate the Thunderbird Profile?

Comment: Have a look at this article "Thunderbird unified folders not working after moving my profile". https://superuser.com/questions/306379/thunderbird-unified-folders-not-working-after-moving-my-profile?rq=1 The accepted answer should help.

Comment: There are issues with migrating a Thunderbird profile from one OS to another because of the EOL characters (\r, \n and combos thereof).

Comment: @vssher I did exactly what the solution said (delete panacea.dat from the profile folder and all .msf files from its subfolders). But the result was the same as before: The first time I started Thunderbird after moving the profile folder everything was OK,  but from the second time on it showed only the error code from the screenshot.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Which difference is there between EOL in Windows 7 and Windows 10? Do you know what a VM is?

Comment: I have found the culprits: When I restore the original files **addonStartup.json.lz4** and **extensions.json** after the first run of Thunderbird then the error does NOT occur and the mails are visible!!! Does this mean that the installed extensions are the cause of the error???

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to repeat this step each time before I start Thunderbird! Obviously, Thunderbird saves these files each time when it runs. So I will try to remove all extensions from the original Thunderbird on the old computer and then resave the Thunderbird profile folder from the old computer to the new computer. Let's see if it works.

Comment: EUREKA!!! It worked!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, some specific extensions can cause this error after a Thunderbird migration. The solution in such a case is to remove all extensions from Thunderbird on the old computer BEFORE you migrate the Thunderbird Profile to the new computer. It worked successfully in my case. (Maybe make a note of the installed extensions before you remove them).